# How to check if specified char exists on Android ? (jss/css/whatever/…)

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, fonts

I have problem with some unicode (utf-8) character on Android. It's displayer as non existing (crossed out rectangle). It's there some way how to check if char exists?

I was trying to check it by `FontFaceSet.check()` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check ) but it's not working :(

my code looks like:

```js
document.fonts.check('700 24px / 36px Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif', '⮝');
```

where `⮝` is my char and long string is computed style from `window.getComputedStyle( myElement, null ).getPropertyValue( 'font' )`

It returns `true`, like character exists, but still this char cannot be show. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`FontFaceSet.check` [does not check if a specific character exists in a font](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Aug/0330.html), only if *any* character in the range of that character exists. You can try rendering the text to a canvas and checking if the rendering is the same as a Unicode character that is known not to exist:

```js
function isLetterRenderable(letter) {
  if (!document.fonts.check('700 24px / 36px Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif', letter)) return false;
  let can;
  if (window.OffscreenCanvas) {
    can = new OffscreenCanvas(50, 50);
  } else {
    can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.height = 50;
    can.width = 50;
  }
  const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = '700 10px Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText(letter, 10, 10);
  const imgData1 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
  ctx.fillText("῿", 10, 10);
  const imgData2 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
  // drawing of character must differ from drawing of known invalid character
  return !imgData1.data.every((x, i) => imgData2.data[i] === x);
}

console.log("a ->", isLetterRenderable("a"));
console.log("ꯃ ->", isLetterRenderable("ꯃ"));
console.log(" ->", isLetterRenderable(""));
console.log("⮝ ->", isLetterRenderable("⮝"));
console.log(" ->", isLetterRenderable(""));
```

Note that some browsers (Firefox does it on my system) will automatically generate "pseudo-letters" that look like [image: 010EB0 in a square]. These look like actual unique letters to `isLetterRenderable` above, so it first checks using `document.fonts.check` since while that function returning `true` is meaningless in this context, if it returns `false` we know for sure that the glyph can't be rendered. But if some letters in a range are renderable, and some are pseduo-letters, then it is very hard to detect which ones have associated glyphs.